# Wrap line of <input> tag

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, html-input

I would like to wrap some text in `<input>` tag. When I use `word-wrap: break-word`, its doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You mean Placeholder? Did you hear about textarea?

Comment: Why not using a `<textarea>` ?

Comment: @andreas because my task is doing wrap with `<input>` tag

Comment: It does not allow line breaks... https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-type-text-keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element), it's not possible to break lines in an input field:

> Text with no line breaks

Instead you will have to use a `<textarea>` (because it is the text input element that is made for line breaks), e.g.:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: Probably better to reference the official spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element

Comment: Right! Updated the answer. Thanks!